# C# Obtaining Namespace Based on CSProj settings

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

Is there a way to obtain the .csproj Default Namespace and Visual Studios understanding it without using preprocessor directives?

For example:

CS Project 1 has a Default Namespace of **SomeCompany.ProductA**

CS Project 2 has a Default Namesapce of **SomeCompany.ProductB**

CS Project 1 has a cs file that exists in BaseClasses/MySpecialBase.cs

CS Project 2 has a *linked file* to that same file in the other project. This way maintaining one file version, without using different assemblies.

CS Project 2 now however has a cs file that references something from CS Project 1, so the class namespace would now be incorrect.

Is there a keyword that can be used in the single CS file to use the currently csproject file Default Namespace

IE: [MyDefaultNameSpace].BaseClasses

I would like to avoid doing #if #else if possible, so I don't have to add symbols.

```
namespace [somekeywordhere].BaseClasses
{
     class MySpecialBase
     {
        ....
     }
}
```

Comment: The linked file is going to still have the same namespace - nothing about linking the file will change the source.  But you could instead use a T4 template in project 2 that would copy the file from project 1, use CodeDom to read and update the namespace, and then write out the new file in project 2 as the output of the T4 template.  The IDE will run the template, so shouldn't be too tricky to keep it up to date. Would that work? Need an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to use the "Default Namespace" from within source code. It is used by the boilerplate T4 templates to automagically prepare new files, but it is a Visual Studio parameter and not an actual property of the code.

As you said, this can be done with some tricky usage of `#if`s and symbols, or as DaveC said you could prepare a T4 template that generates the copy correcting the namespace (this would not use linking). In any case, this involves some work.

I see sort of an inversion of logical hierarchy when a deeper-level construct (your shared-by-linking file) uses something more specific (code from one or the other project), since I always used linked files to handle something like global version attributes or other assembly properties (e.g. company, product), so this shared file was never dependent on anything "logically above" it. But I guess you have your reasons, just making it clear.

Comment: Correct, I have my reason for it, even if its not optimal. Just trying to be clever.  T4 we thought about, ifdef sounds easiest.  Just was making sure there wasn't something in .net before I did that. So technically, this is the correct response unless someone can prove otherwise, or a future version of .net has some new keyword to be included.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Reflection API" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx
for eg.

```
System.Type myNameSpaceAndClassName = this.getType()
```

Comment: I am talking about the actual source in the project... not doing it at runtime.  IE:  namesapce [somethinghere].BaseClasses{ class MySpecialBase {...}}